# Building a REST API, using firebase as a backend

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Currently, I am using firebase to store data, I would like to expose some of the data by creating an API that others can consume. I am using this documentation as reference https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/
The user is created by issuing an HTTP POST request to the Auth signupNewUser endpoint. The response is an id token which is valid for an hour. Is this the token to be used for allowing a user to access API endpoints? I see that there are four types of token which firebase provides and I am not sure which one to use and when. Which token should be used to authenticate a user who will consume an API and which token should be used to authorize which access a user should have? Also, my other concern is that in order to use firebase rest API to create a user it requires to have API key attached to every request, is that a safe practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to pass along the ID token to API requests that need to [verify the ID token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) using the Admin SDK, then authorize the user for whatever they're trying to do.

Comment: thank you for you response, I was looking into admin sdk but was not sure if that was what I needed, happy to know I am on a right path.

Comment: What about rest authentication that firebase offer? https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth What is difference between using that for authentication and making use of admin sdk for authenication ?

Comment: The REST API is just another client type access.  It has nothing to do with the Admin SDK.

Comment: user gets an firebase id token when he sings into the app, and he also can get a referesh token what is the use case for admin? Authorization can be done using firebase rules, is that not enough?

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I understand your question. This doesn't sound like it's related to the original question of building a REST API, since security rules have nothing to do with that.

Comment: How do you limit what data user can access? We would like to build a rest api but it will not be public, users need to authenticate themselves and once they do so they can only access certain parts of the database and can perform certain actions

Comment: That is definitely a completely different question than the one you originally asked, and it's rather broad in scope. But you should know that security rules don't apply to the server SDKs, only to the client SDKs where Firebase Authentication is also integrated.